# Who is the herbsman?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

My first arms the men of the herb,
After, my second hydrates it with love.
I created a space of cynical joy,
Bringing flight to a lovers' embrace.

Who am I?

Comment: @John it could be... what's that?

Comment: Call it poetic license. Rest assured this is a PG-rated riddle.

Comment: I am a little worried that the wordplay is a bit obscure though... I won't count my upvotes until there's an answer :-P

Comment: @Ant_P, I totally understand. It sounds like a good one though.

Comment: Can we have some hints?

Answer (score 1):

My first arms the men of the herb,
After, my second hydrates it with love.
I created a space of cynical joy,
Bringing flight to a lovers' embrace.

Who am I?

> You are head chef in a brigade kitchen.  Your first line chefs prepare salads, vegetable mise in place and garnishes, or poetically, men of the herb.  Your sous chefs make sauces and perhaps saute.  Emeril Lagasse always refers to roux sauces as sauces of love as they cook low and slow.  Calling a brigade kitchen a space of cynical joy probably means you've worked in a restaurant (Tony Bourdain is who I picture as embodying "cynical joy").  Restaurants that focus on haute French technique are going to be special occasion or date-night places for lovers.  And the sommelier might even have a wine flight on offer.

Answer (score 0):

You are

> A tribal spiritual leader.

To be exact

> a Shaman from Native American tradition. They work with hallucinogenic drugs/herbs to transcend the physical plane. This herb is pivotal to tribal spiritualism.

My first arms the men of the herb,

> Your prayers/blessing steel the resolve of the tribesmen. Giving them strength and courage.

After, my second hydrates it with love.

> After war, peace is restored by smoking the peace pipe. You lead this process.

I created a space of cynical joy,

> The herb(s) you work with create an artificial joy, which is lost once the high is lost. The more you crave it, the worse off you are.

Bringing flight to a lovers' embrace.

> It (may) elevate the senses, making an intimate experience more intense.